# Create two digit number inside a loop

Tags: angular

Hi i have numbers to be created inside a for loop, so for numbers from 1 to 9 i need to add '0' to it so it becomes 01,02,03...09,10....
So i did like this .

```
for (var a = 1; a < 30; a++) {
                var zero;
                if (a < 10) {
                    console.log("in if",a)
                    zero = 0;
                }else{
                    zero = ''
                }
                console.log(zero);
                this.everyMonth.push({
                    day: zero  a,
                    })
       }
```

This code works good like for numbers from 1 to 9 falls in if statement and others in else

What i need is to add this zero inside the object and get 01,02....09,10,11...30
Could someone help me, by giving me samples

Comment: You're missing a `+`: `day: zero + a,`

Comment: would that add these two numbers

Comment: Not if they are strings. Take a step back and do a little reading on strings vs numbers. I am guessing you have a text book somewhere as this is for a class assignment? This is probably covered in one of the first chapters/sections.

Answer (score 0):

In JavaScript, your variable can be sometimes a number, sometimes a string. But it is not a good practice if you don't want to get confused. I have made some explicit type changes.

And since we are in Typescript wiht Angular, let's be a bit more careful with our types !

Moreover, to concatenate 2 strings together, you have to use the `+` operator.

```
for (var a = 1; a < 30; a++) {
    let zero: string; // Typescript / ECMAScript syntax, preferred to the "var zero;" syntax. 
    if (a < 10) {
        zero = '0';
    } else {
        zero = '';
    }
    this.everyMonth.push({
        day: zero + a.toString(),
    });
}
```

You can also shorten all the `let` and `if` block like in @Aman Jain's answer :

```
    let zero: string;
    if (a < 10) {
        zero = '0';
    } else {
        zero = '';
    }
```

is the same as

```
    let zero: string = a < 10 ? '0' : '';
```

Answer (score 0):

Write this code and it will work

```
for (var a = 1; a < 30; a++) {
  let zero = a < 10 ? '0' : '';
  everyMonth.push({
    day: zero + a,
  })
}
```